# lxml only recognizes first import in XSD with multiple imports into same namespace

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

I am trying to validate XML file against its XSD schema. lxml is not recognizing second import btype as I am importing it into same namespace. When I add a separate name space for the btype it works.

**main.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:bo="http://loremipsum.org/1/"
           targetNamespace="http://loremipsum.org/bi/1/"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
    <xs:import namespace="http://loremipsum.org/1/" schemaLocation="../atype.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://loremipsum.org/1/" schemaLocation="../btype.xsd"/>

    <xs:element name="batch">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="atype" type="bo:AType"> </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="btype" type="bo:BType"> </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**atype.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://loremipsum.org/1/"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
    <xs:complexType name="AType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ecm" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="type" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0">
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**btype:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://loremipsum.org/1/"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
    <xs:complexType name="BType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

These XSD's are working fine even with multiple imports into same namespace in apache camel.
is there a problem with lxml or my XSDs are wrong?

Comment: Is there a specific error message you're getting? Does it occur when you load the schema or when you validate the document? Can you include some code in your question that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @larsks I get the below error.

lxml.etree.XMLSchemaParseError: element decl. 'btype', attribute 'type': The QName value '{http://loremipsum.org/1/}BType' does not resolve to a(n) type definition., line 13

It occurs when I create the schema.